# How can i display an alert after Response.End

Tags: c#, asp.net

I already know, codes after the `Response.End()` will not work. I am trying to `alert` a `message box` after `Response.End`. Basically what i am doing is i will read data from `Excel` file and check for the missing data in the excel file. I will collect all the data that was missing from the `Excel` file and write them all to a `text` file and will prompt that using the following code

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("ErrorLog") + "\\" + "ErrorLog.txt";
string FileName = "Errorlog" + ".txt";
string[] createText = { sb.ToString() };
File.WriteAllLines(strPath, createText);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + "");
strPath.Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(strPath);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

After this i would like to display an alert box saying some thing like `Invalid Data`. But i would like to know how can i do that after `Response.End`

// Updated code as per `lcarus`

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("ErrorLog") + "\\" + "ErrorLog.txt";
string[] createText = { sb.ToString() };
File.WriteAllLines(strPath, createText);
ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
string strconfirm = "<script>if(window.confirm('Excel file has Invalid data.')){window.location.href='/Excel1/ErrorLog/ErrorLog.txt'}</script>";
 CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in sort of 2 parts:

Collect the missing data, save it to a file (By the way, you need to create a unique name for the log file unless you are planning to support only one concurrent user on your site) and use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to call a function like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"somekey",
"alert('Some data missing!'); window.location.href='http://your_site.com/path_to_log_file'",true);
```

You will know `path_to_log_file` since you are the one generating it on the server side.

The user will see the alert and after clicking "OK" the log file will be displayed on his browser or asked to download it, depending on whether the browser knows how to handle the file (this is usually determined by the extension of the file).

**UPDATE**

Sample HTTPHandler implementation.

You can construct the link like this from code behind:

```
window.location.href='FileDownloader.ashx?FileName=ErrorLog.txt'

public class FileDownloader: IHttpHandler
{
       public bool IsReusable
       {
            get { return true; }
       }

       public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       {
            // This is where you read the log file and add the content disposition
            //header
            string strPath = Server.MapPath("ErrorLog") + "\\" + context.Request.QueryString["FileName"];

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + context.Request.QueryString["FileName"] + "");
            strPath.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
            context.Response.WriteFile(strPath);
            context.Response.End();

       }
}
```

Comment: So instead of `Httpcontext` i would like to use `ClientScript` right

Comment: @User: Correct. You should be able to get a reference to a ClientScriptManager object by accessing the ClientScript property on the page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript.aspx

Comment: But i am not getting the download option i will update my question with my code can you check once

Comment: @User: What exactly is the problem with downloading the file? Is it being displayed instead of the user being asked to download it? If so, I explained on my answer that this will be the case for known file types by the browser. You have 2 alternatives: 1. Change the log file extension to something uncommon (.log, for example). or 2. Create an HTTPHandler that can stream the log file and add the content-disposition header so that the user is asked to download it regardless of extension.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5364/discussion-between-user-and-icarus)

Answer (score 0):

first declare a protected string var in your page class :

```
public partial class YourASPPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        protected string Alert = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              Alert = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('something alerted here');</script>";
        }
}
```

then in your aspx file, write somwthing like that when you want to show your alert (just not in a script tag) :

```
<%= Alert %>
```

Comment: I didn't get this `<%=Alert%>`

Comment: Ok i used Iframe and write as per you said but still i am unable to achieve the required

Comment: <%= Alert %> put the protected string Alert var that you declare in you html code.and because it is a script contain an alert, an alert just shown :) , it is easy way :)

Answer (score -1):

Calling javascript function from code behind will not work after Response.End(); But can use beforeunload, it will fire after Response.End();

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (){
            //here your function
    });
```